# "Object doesn't support this property or method" occurs, when I try to call method from applet

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, applet

"Object doesn't support this property or method" occurs from javascript, and stops at line, where process a call of method from applet, for Liferay Portal

javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function processSigning(){
        var applet = document.applets["SignApplet"];
        var path_to_certificate = document.getElementById("certificate").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var filePath = document.getElementById("documentSign").value;
        applet.filePath = document.getElementById("documentSign").value;

        //at this line, call of method from applet, javascript stops, but applet has this method
        //and it's public
        applet.profileTestPKCS12(path_to_certificate, pass);

        document.getElementById("file").value = applet.getDocumentString(filePath);
        document.getElementById("sign").value = applet.getSignString();
        document.getElementById("cert").value = applet.getCertificateString();
        document.forms['mainForm'].submit();
//        document.getElementById("mainForm").submit();


    }
</script>
```

html's snippet for applet:

```
<APPLET name="SignApplet" mayscript code="SignApplet.class" archive="<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/lib/SignApplet.jar")%>, <%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/lib/crypto.tsp.jar")%>, <%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/lib/crypto.gammaprov.jar")%>" height=500 width=500 style="display:none;">
    <PARAM name="boxmessage" value="Please wait, while applet is loading">
</APPLET>
```

Comment: at what line the error occurs?

Comment: at this "applet.profileTestPKCS12(path_to_certificate, pass);"

Comment: This may sound silly, but to prevent those kinds of issues, I usually verify that the object exists. Something like: if(document.applets["SignApplet"]){// do stuf . . .}

Comment: What if it doesn't exist, but I must use this applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<APPLET name="SignApplet" ... style="display:none;">
```

W3C on the [The 'display' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

> (value) **none**
>       This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; **the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely.**

Answer (score 2):

In applet u should avoid using display:none..... when u defines as none, in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout.... So better try **visiblity:hidden** property instead of **display:none**...

Comment: actually I do not need to show the applet, it does calculations